# Obtain virtual output directory path in geoprocessing service

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I am publishing a geoprocessing service and I want to be able to access the virtual output directory path configured for the service.

Now I know that gp services will magically return virtual paths for output parameters of data type file, but is there a way to access the virtual output directory path string directly?

right now I'm doing something very hackish:

```
def get_results_virtual_path(resultsFilePath):
    file_url = urlparse.urljoin('file:', urllib.pathname2url(resultsFilePath))
    if 'directories' in file_url:
        return SERVER_VIRTUAL_DIRECTORIES + file_url.split(r'directories')[1]
    else:
        return file_url
```

Its basically hard-coding the virtual path.  Now I know the virtual path can be complicated by load-balancers and subdomains and such, but all I want to do is read the environment variable from the service properties.